# spring bean is null in mockito test

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I'm using spring 5 and mockito, but in a test process i have a problem where my **bean** is done **null** and i get a NullPointerException, how can i fix it?
infact, my SpringContext.getBean returns null but it work correctly when the application is in runtime mode.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.novinkish.batch.ParallerMakerTest.testSendData(ParallerMakerTest.java:53)
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.novinkish.batch.util.SpringContext.getBean(SpringContext.java:14)
```

my test class is like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

public class ParallerMakerTest {

```
@Mock
private CommonRestCallerImpl restCallerImpl;

@Test
public void testSendData(){

    PersonDTO personDTO_1 = new PersonDTO("1111111111", "name_1", "L_name_1", "2000/05/09", (short) 0);
    PersonDTO personDTO_2 = new PersonDTO(4646L, "1111111111", "name_1", "L_name_1", "2000/05/09", (short) 1);
    List<PersonDTO> resultDtoList = new ArrayList<PersonDTO>();

    try {
        when(restCallerImpl.callService(ServiceNameJNDI.SAVE_PERSON, personDTO_1, PersonDTO.class)).thenReturn(personDTO_2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    PersonSessionParallerMaker maker = new PersonSessionParallerMaker(restCallerImpl, Arrays.asList(personDTO_1));
    pool.execute(maker);
    try {
        pool.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    resultDtoList = (List<PersonDTO>) pool.invoke(maker);
    Assert.assertNotNull(resultDtoList);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, ((PersonDTO)resultDtoList.get(0)).getStatus().intValue());

}
```

and my class is:

```
    public class PersonSessionParallerMaker extends RecursiveTask {

private CommonRestCaller restCaller;

private List<PersonDTO> initList = new ArrayList<PersonDTO>();
private List<PersonDTO> resultList = new ArrayList<PersonDTO>();

private PersonDTO target;

public PersonSessionParallerMaker(CommonRestCaller restCaller, List<PersonDTO> initList) {
    this.initList = initList;
    this.restCaller = restCaller;
}

public PersonSessionParallerMaker(PersonDTO target) {
    this.target = target;
}

@Override
protected Object compute() {

    /*MASTER Thread*/
    if (target == null) {
        for (PersonDTO personDTO : initList) {

            /*CREATE FORK (SUB THREAD)*/
            PersonSessionParallerMaker parallerMaker = new PersonSessionParallerMaker(personDTO);
            invokeAll(parallerMaker);
            resultList.add((PersonDTO) parallerMaker.join());
        }

        return resultList;

    } else if (target.getStatus() == 0) {
        callService();
        return target;
    } else
        return null;
}

public void callService() {

    System.out.println("1.restCaller = " + restCaller);
    /*For Unit Test*/
    if (restCaller == null) {
        System.out.println("2.restCaller = " + restCaller);
        restCaller = (CommonRestCaller) SpringContext.getBean(CommonRestCallerImpl.class);
        System.out.println("3.restCaller = " + restCaller);
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("target.toString() = " + target.toString());
        target = (PersonDTO) restCaller.callService(ServiceNameJNDI.SAVE_PERSON, target, PersonDTO.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        target.setStatus((short) 2);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ofcourse it is `null`. It is a Mockito test NOT a spring test. No spring involved no features of Spring available.

Comment: so how can i create an appropriate test for PersonSessionParallerMaker.class, can you help me?

Comment: As a side note: ForkJoinPool to make multiple rest calls is a poor idea. Consider: 1. Saving in batch 2. Using non-blocking rest client

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up unit testing and integration testing here.

What you have written, is a unit test. Unit tests run - per definiton - isolated from the whole application, therefore you have no access to the application context. The purpose of a unit test is to test **one specific class**.

If you want to test the behaviour of your **whole application**, you have to write an integration test.
See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#integration-testing-with-springboottest for further reading.